# Why can't I change the output of puts "string" by over-riding .to_s or initialize on String?

Tags: ruby

I've replaced a method to_s inside of String class,
but as I can see, when I run `puts "string"`, ruby calls not the to_s method.

```
def add_method(cls)
  cls.class_eval do
    def initialize
      self.new('you hacked')
    end

    def to_s
      'you hacked'
    end
  end
end

add_method String

puts "zxzxzzx"
puts "zxzxzzx".to_s
```

which outputs:

```
>> zxzxzzx
>> you hacked
```

How to replace this implicit initialization ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> when I run puts "string", ruby calls not the to_s method.

It's already a string, no conversion is done. For more information, see source for [IO#puts](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-i-puts).

And also, that attempted trick with initializer won't work. Return value of `initialize` is ignored. It can only be used to set properties on already created object, it can't replace that object.